# Visual Studio Extensibility SDK - Listen to git events

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, git-commit, git-push

I have a Visual Studio plugin and I'm trying to listen to the Repo Push or Repo Commit event.

Is there a way to listen to a git event?

The plugin is for VS2022 and VS2019.